# print() not outputting to the debug area

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, watchkit

I have a method in a custom class with a `print()` statement in it.  The class is instantiated and the method is called from my iOS app's ViewController.  When the method is called, most of its functionality is executed, however the `print()` statement doesn't appear in the debug area.

Is there something special I need to do to get that output to be displayed in the debug area?

This is a WatchKit app, though I don't know if that's necessarily relevant.

Comment: can you please try to use print() in other method like awekWithContext: and check if print() is working or not

Comment: @HitendraHckr It does, but the print() statements in question are in classes instantiated and called from the ViewController of the iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

no, you don't need to do anything special to make it show up. It should automatically show up. However, make sure you have "All output" selected at the bottom and not just debugger output. If you only select debugger output, it won't show up.

[image: All Output]

Comment: Thanks.  I do have "All Output" selected.  I just added the clarification to the question that the ViewController that is calling the custom class is the iOS app's ViewController.

Comment: can you share more code so we can understand the issue better?

Comment: Another question I asked, which has the relevant code, may be related (I strongly suspect it is): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985589/avaudioplayer-not-playing-sound

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon check my answer on your other post. The problem is with the function not calling it. So it has nothing to do with print or anything special about printing.